# Struts2 datepicker not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, struts2, dojo, calendar, datepicker

We are using Struts2 dojo plugin 2.3.15.3, the datepicker works fine in internet explorer, safari and firefox, but it does not work in chrome. The field just disappears! I tried using the incognito mode, and it works there too!

I have already updated chrome and removed all extension, but still not calendar. Any suggestions?

Comment: S2 dojo plugin is deprecated. If you want to use some plugin for js then use s2 jquery plugin.

Comment: Did you specify head tag? `<sd:head/>` or `<s:head/>`

Comment: Try with the version which is compatible with your struts version. Try with different version.